# JavaScript works fine in the console but not in the linked .js file

Tags: javascript, html

I know this is a really annoying question that you have all seen a thousand times, but I can manipulate something in the DOM with my javascript fine, but when it comes to being executed in a separate .js file it does nothing. I have tried everything, if someone could help it would be much appreciated.

Here is my JS/HTML. As you can see I even linked it with the fullpath:

```js
function randomRGB() {
    const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    return `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`
}

const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');

h1.style.color = randomRGB();
setInterval(function(){
    h1.style.color = randomRGB();
}, 500 )
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Users/goldenpanda/Documents/VSCODE/RandomColors/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems to work fine, what's the problem?

Comment: Have you checked the console in your browser for errors and/or warnings?

Comment: It's a problem with the readystate. The dom hasn't finished loading, while the script tries to find h1.

Comment: When I try to load the index file in the browser it is blank, no color, it seems as if the .js file is not linking properly for some reason. I have had this issue before in the past with JavaScript files.

Comment: @Mouser does putting the script tag after the h1 not fix that? If not, how do I do so?

Comment: What's the setup of your folder?

Comment: both the files are stored in the same separate folder located at `/Users/goldenpanda/Documents/VSCODE/RandomColors/`

Comment: Have you tried just using the local path as in `<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>`

Comment: I have indeed @FelixO'Brien

Comment: If it couldn't load the JS file there would be an error in the console.

Comment: What about removing the type or putting all the code into a script tag in the html page. I understand there would be an error but sometimes it's literally just the smallest things. If that doesn't work then it's something else. What browser are you using?

Comment: Truthfully, I am working through springboard and am just trying to learn how to do things the proper way for future reference (in the event that I was doing something wrong) @FelixO'Brien, but you're right putting it in a script tag on the html page does make it work

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine for me.

Comment: I just put the code into two files and put the URL of the HTML file into Chrome.

Comment: @GoldenPanda Then it's probably the development environment. I would suggest just running it normally (i.e open html file in browser or through a web server) Visual studio code is a great editor which you can get an extension for called live web server. That should make it easier for you.

Comment: Thanks @FelixO'Brien looking into it now.